# keystore and trustore not working together

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, keystore, truststore

I have an existing application with configured trustore to connect to ldap

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=config/keystore.jks 
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=p@ssw0rd -jar test.jar
```

Then I want the application to configure to use https.  I use a separately generated keystore for this.  Since I am using spring boot, I added the following:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=config/keystore.jks 
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=p@ssw0rd 
     -Dserver.ssl.key-alias=kstore2 
     -Dserver.ssl.key-store=config/kstore2.keystore 
     -Dserver.ssl.key-store-password=kstore2
     -jar test.jar
```

When I run, I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Users.....\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.5....\config\keystore.jks 
(The system cannot find the path specified).
```

If I run only with -Djavax.net....., it's working but I am back to http.
If I run only with -Dserver.ssl...., it's working and I can get https.
But if I run with them together, I got the error.

Comment: The problem is you are setting the global trust store which is used for everything. Instead you need to specifically configure the truststore for your ldap client.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, could you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path for the trust store and key store. Are you sure the key store is located under the config directory where you are starting your application?